# How can I return the filename of the image upload to insert into DB?

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter, function

Does anybody know how I can get the name of the file that has just been uploaded and then pass it to the index() function so it can be inserted into my database?

It's written in codeigniter and here is the code from my Form Controller.

Thanks.

```
public function index() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nominee', 'Nominee', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[self_nominees.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('imageupload', 'Image Upload', 'callback__image_upload');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('videoupload', 'Video Upload', 'callback__video_upload');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //Load the form
        $this->template('form.php');
    }
    else
    {       
        //Run code to add into the database
        $formdata = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // this prevent from XSS attacks
        $this->load->model('users');
        $this->users->self_nominate($formdata['nominee'], $formdata['email'], $formdata['location'], $formdata['category'], $formdata['description'], 'image', 'video');                                    

        //Load the thankyou page
        $this->template('thankyou.php');
    }

}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------
    Image Upload Function
----------------------------------------------------------------*/

function _image_upload()
{
      $this->load->library('upload');

        // Check if there was a file uploaded
        if (!empty($_FILES['imageupload']['name']))
        {
            // Specify configuration for File 1
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';       

            // Initialize config for File 1 
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            // Upload file 1
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('imageupload'))
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $imageerrors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->form_validation->set_message('_image_upload', $imageerrors);

                return false;
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Right from the Docs, found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

```
$this->upload->data()
```

This is a helper function that returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded. Here is the array prototype:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

`$this->upload->data()` has all the info you could ever need about the file!

Comment: Yeh, I have used this (Not in the script above). It works great and im assuming this is how i get the data. But my question is. How can i pass it from the _image_upload() function back to index() so i can insert it?

Comment: I'm confused. Where is the `image_upload()` function located? Is it a model? If it's a model, just `return` the value and have the controller get it like this: `$new_file = $this->your_model->image_upload();`

Comment: Be advised, file uploads are usually handled by the controller, and in that case, transfer the file name using CodeIgniter's `$this->session` class.

Comment: image_upload() is in the controller too. and video_upload() is below that, i just didnt include it in the code above as it would be the same. I have tried things like:
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$image_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

and just get undefined variable errors.

Comment: That should work... but are you sure you're executing `$this->upload->do_upload()`? If the variables aren't there, the upload probably didn't happen. `$this->upload->display_errors();` should help you find out.

Comment: yep, its working because the file is uploading fine. if there are errors it doesnt upload and displays them fine. its just not submitting the filename in the db

Comment: If you have a file that's being uploaded along with a form, why not run it inside `index()`? Then you have access to the variables right there.

Comment: I had that, but i needed it be optional. you dont always upload a file. do you think it has something to do with returning the variable?

Comment: If it's optional, then just do this: `if($_FILES AND isset($_FILES['field_name']['name'])) )`. That will keep everything in-house.

Comment: The code snippet in your question is completely irrelevant. I'm not sure how you get the file uploaded if the form submits to `index()`

Comment: because of this:     $this->form_validation->set_rules('imageupload', 'Image Upload', 'callback__image_upload');

Comment: Ah. I see. In any case, I personally feel you would be better of with the `if` statement in the `index()` function.

Comment: Yeah, I had that and there were too many other problems. Like if i did submit an image, the image errors would not prevent the form from submitting. This time it works perfect bar inserting the filename into the db.

Comment: The problem is, your callback has no way of communicating with your `index()` method. There's just no way. SESSION variables would work, but that's sloppy. If you run `$this->upload->data()` in index(), it doesn't know if an upload even occurred, because is hasn't on `index()`. It looks like you have to move it. :/

Comment: yeah thats the problem. how about if i return an array?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16421/discussion-between-chris-and-david)

Comment: I repeat, you cannot have a callback function in a CodeIgniter form_validation series communicate back with the source method. You have to use SESSION, a database - something.